# align="center" within wordpress page does not work

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to center a div inside a wordpress page, but it's not working

http://dev.turnim.com/clients/snc/?page_id=8

The div with the class main_top_row should be centered and 1000px width

i tried using ID and CLASS, but none will work

Anyone has an idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: "Anyone has an idea what is going wrong here?" Yes, you seem to be using 1990s web dev techniques. Care to elaborate what CSS you "tried using ID and CLASS" so we can actually help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `align="center"` for this (or anything else for that matter).

Add the following to your style.css file:

```
.main_top_row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

This sets your left and right margins on the div to auto. When combined with a fixed width the div is centred.